# Why Visual Studio abruptly stops the program and shows error #include gtkmm.h not found

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, settings, gtkmm, vcpkg

I've been trying to run a pre build program by my friend which includes vcpkg package and it runs well but failed abruptly saying that the gtkmm.h header file not found. I think I was searching for some debugging settings and misplaced something which killed the whole debugging process.
Can anyone please tell me about the mistake I've been doing that the program keep showing the error for gtkmm[image: screen popping up when I try to load the pre-build app]
[image: Configuration of my project vcpkg debugging option]

Comment: If I understand well, the program you are running is already built (i.e. you have an EXE) and when you start it from Visual Studio (e.g. by pressing F5) if runs fine (e.g. you can interract with its UI). Then, at some point in its execution, it fails with the above mentionned error? Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, I've already fixed the error by deleting the pre-build files and . Sln files. I've deleted all the debug folders content which relieved the program of all settings and hence was able to debug the program again without any error. I've learnt the issue well and have realised how to troubleshoot visual studio errors.

Comment: Glad you solved it! Perhaps you could either write an answer (for future readers) or delete your post. Thanks!

Comment: I'll be adding every information related to such issues. The answer was really the easiest one. When working with vcpkg package and the project has been debugged from some other machine, while copying it to any other machine you've to delete the debug folder and the . Sln files . This is really handy as you'll give the systen a way to debug the codes again and create respective path for vcpkg package.